# Topology: Open subset contained in interior of parent set

Tags: general-topology

if $A\subset B$ and $A$ is open, show $A$ is contained in the interior of $B$.

Does it makes sense that since $A$ is open and $A\subset B$, then the $\operatorname{Int}(A)⊂\operatorname{Boundary}(A)\subset B$.

Thus, $\operatorname{Int}(A)\subset B$,

Comment: This is not about topography.

Comment: Please make this into a comment: I'm pretty sure the OP means "General Topology".

Comment: yes sorry i was not paying attention i will fix it.

Comment: Your solution is not correct since $Boundary(A)\not\subset B$. Consider some $A=B$ and $A,B open$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $int(B)$ by definition is the largest open set contained in $B$. Since $A$ is open, and $A \subseteq B$, by definition of $int(B)$, $A \subseteq int(B)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall z \in A=A^0, \exists \ a>0: D[z,a] \subset A =A^0 \subseteq B$$

Now $$z \in B^0 \iff \exists \ b>0:D[z,b] \subseteq B$$

Choose $b=a$. QED